How can I fix 'greenlet_spawn has not been called' error when using fixture and SqlAlchemy?
Pytest + Async SqlAlchemy + async_sessionmaker not working
repo: https://github.com/gabszs/CV-API

error -> sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
when trying to run this fixtures at same test:

@pytest.mark.asyncio # ------->>>> RUNS WELL
async def test_user(user):
    ic(user)


@pytest.mark.asyncio # ------->>>> RUNS WELL
async def test_other_test(other_user):
    ic(other_user)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_both_users(user, other_user): # ------->>>> BROKING
    ic(user, other_user)

but when i try to run individualy, both task work WELL(EXP: async def test_other_test(other_user))
also, when uses the fixture session, and do await session.execute(stmt), the users fixtures runs well together.
@pytest.mark.asyncio  # ------->>>> RUNS WELL
async def test_both_users(session, user, other_user):
    stmt = select(User)
    result = await session.execute(stmt)
    users = result.fetchall()
    ic(user, other_user, users)

my
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop(request):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def app():
    with ExitStack():
        yield init_app(init_db=False)

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c
        
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def db(event_loop):
    sessionmanager.init(settings.TEST_DATABASE_URL)
    async with sessionmanager.connect() as conn:
        await sessionmanager.drop_all(conn)
        await sessionmanager.create_all(conn)
    yield sessionmanager
    async with sessionmanager.connect() as conn:
        await sessionmanager.drop_all(conn)
    await sessionmanager.close()

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def session(db):
    async with db.session() as session:
        yield session

@pytest_asyncio.fixture()
async def user(session):
    user = UserFactory()
    session.add(user)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(user)
    return user

@pytest_asyncio.fixture()
async def other_user(session):
    other_user = UserFactory()
    session.add(other_user)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(other_user)
    return other_user

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def session_override(app, connection_test):
    async def get_db_override():
        async with sessionmanager.session() as session:
            yield session

    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = get_db_override

MODELS -> https://github.com/gabszs/CV-API/tree/develop/app/models
SESSIONMANAGER (IN THE FINAL OF THE FILE): https://github.com/gabszs/CV-API/blob/develop/app/core/database.py
im using a postgresql container connection: 'postgresql+asyncpg://app_user:app_password@localhost:5432/app_db'
but also already tried with psycopg instead of asyncpg
i dont have any idea how to deal with this, my objective is to create a users fixture to add users, using async_session
I expect to run the fixture in the scope of each texts, only using it when requested and discharging them after the tests
